# Write Text To 'RichTextBox' in WinForm From Console Application

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a console application that starts a windows form in a separate thread like this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(StartForm);
        t.Start();

    }
    static public void StartForm()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

- Form Conatains Richtextbox Control .

My question : How do i write Text to the Richtextbox control in the form from my application (and from anyThread)?

PS: i also Need the Console to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Invoke` to write text to `RichTextBox` from background thread.

In Form1 designer, change `richTextBox1.Modifiers` to `public`, in order to access it form other thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(StartForm);
    t.Start();

    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    form.UIThread(() => form.richTextBox1.Text += text);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static Form1 form;
public static void StartForm()
{
    form = new Form1();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(form);
}

public static void UIThread(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)            // You're access from other thread
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);       // Invoke to access UI element
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to update your form's content from another thread. You can check whether or not you need to do so by checking the [`InvokeRequired`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) property. While you can pass any [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx), you should pass a [`MethodInvoker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate, which is a special delegate made for use with Windows Forms.

For example:

```
if(form.TheRichTextBox.InvokeRequired)
{
    form.TheRichTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
        form.TheRichTextBox.Text += "I had to be invoked!";
    }));
}
else
{
    form.TheRichTextBox.Text += "I didn't have to be invoked!";
}
```